# Design dynamic layouts

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

I need to design a diagram as shown in https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3UBS.jpg dynamically in android.

Can I design it in XML and use it dynamically in my code?

Can someone guide me please or if you can share some tutorials to do this. 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is dynamic about the layout? They all look the same? Surely you can design a 'row' in XML and use it with a RecyclerView or ListView Adapter dynamically binding the data ..

Comment: You can just design it via xml, this looks pretty trivial. Have a look at this http://javatechig.com/android/android-linearlayout-example

Comment: No, i mean the data for  the shop name, logo will be updated from the database. 
I need to create only one view, the other must be added dynamically

Comment: learn 1)Tab layout..http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/ 2)card view..http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465

Comment: @Ishita You can `Create Custom Layout` for this. And use it with `List View` will do this for you. you need to design `XML`.